# for loop 4 DOM elements and their events in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, dom

I am trying to loop these 3 images followed by their ul and li. Once clicked I came across an issue that the event handler isn't listening on any of the images other than the first. Please help me out.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanDaManEker/8hb3dm83/2/)

JS

```
var main = function () {

    var recipeArray = ['drink', 'firstCourse', 'mainDish', 'dessert'];
    var recipeArrayLength = recipeArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < recipeArrayLength; i++) {

        var $checkBoxes = document.createElement('div');
        $checkBoxes.setAttribute("class", "checkBoxes");
        var $recipePicContainer = document.createElement('span');
        $recipePicContainer.setAttribute("class", "recipePicContainer");


        function makeRecipePic() {
            var recipe = document.createElement("IMG");
            recipe.setAttribute("src", "../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg");
            recipe.setAttribute("class", "recipe");
            $recipePicContainer.appendChild(recipe);

        }

        makeRecipePic();

        var mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('mainContainer');
        mainContainer[0].appendChild($checkBoxes);

        var $div = document.createElement('div');
        $div.innerHTML = 'CockTails';
        $recipePicContainer.appendChild($div);
        $checkBoxes.appendChild($recipePicContainer);

        var $recipes = document.createElement("ul");
        var $checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxes');

        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    }
        for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.className = "ingredients";
            li.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");


            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.innerHTML = "Ingredient " + j;

            li.appendChild(a);
            $recipes.appendChild(li);
        }
        var b = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        li.className = "Instructions";

        $checkboxes[0].appendChild($recipes);
        $('.recipes').hide();
        $('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').prependTo(".ingredients");
        $('.mainContainer .recipePicContainer').click(function () {
            $(this).next('ul').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

        });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Your event handler listening the event on each image click, you internal logic is wrong, put console.log()  or alert in click handler function

Comment: Hey @Nitin, I'll give it a try thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only appending the ul and li elements to the first checkbox. Therefore there is nothing to display when the onclick event is triggered for any of the other ones.

```
$checkboxes[0].appendChild($recipes);
```

You need to append children to the other checkboxes like you do here for the first checkbox in order for them to display something.

Comment: OK, I get it.. thanx! ill give this a go.

Comment: So like $checkboxes[i].appendChild($recipes); ?

Comment: Yes something like that @DanEker but make sure you are looping over all the checkboxes elements when you are doing that